# spring - function resolver based on parameter?

Tags: java, spring

I'm after a spring configuration based example whereby, depending on the value of a parameter, a different function is invoked.

I've been googling 'spring function resolver' or something of that sort, but alas I can't seem to find anything online.

So basically, all functions would somehow be stored somewhere, and based on the value of this parameter, call different functions.

e.g "PameterISA" -> invoke A()

"ParameterISB" -> invoke B()

etc....

Is this easily done with Spring?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The object-oriented way of handling this if `PameterISA` and `PameterISB` can be instances of different classes that implements a common interface, then you can use the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
interface Strategy {
    void doIt();
}

class ClassA implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        // execute the code that corresponds to A()
    }
}

class ClassB implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public void doIt() {
        // execute the code that corresponds to B()
    }
}
```

Now, all that you have to do is

```
Strategy PameterISA = new ClassA();
Strategy PameterISB = new ClassB();

// ...

Strategy strategy = // an instance of either ClassA or ClassB
strategy.doIt();    // will call the correct method.
```

---

Alternatively, if the parameter is a `byte`, `short`, `char` `int` (or their boxed counterparts), `enum` or (as of Java 7) `String`, you can use a plain old [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement:

```
switch (parameter) {
    case "PameterISA":
        A();
        break;
    case "PameterISB":
        B();
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(parameter);
}
```

---

Finally, you can use the procedural `if` - `else if` - `else` pattern.